# .NET MVC Razor View: conditionally including razor command

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I have this editorTemplate:

```
@model MyNamespace.Models.SomeModel
@using HtmlHelpers.BeginCollectionItem 

<div>
@using (Html.BeginCollectionItem("someProperty")) {

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.field1, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.field1, new { @class = "form-control" })
        </div>
    </div>

    //more content here

}
</div>
```

I need to conditionally include the `@using (Html.BeginCollectionItem("someProperty")) {}` part depending on a value of the ViewBag.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible
You need to include the `using` in `@ {/// using - without @ }`

example :

```
@{
    if(ViewBag.x==x){
       using (Html.BeginCollectionItem("someProperty")) {}
    }else{
    }
}
```

Comment: that did not work. the problem is, all the content of the view is INSIDE the using statement (the closing '}' is near the end of the code).